# After Magento upgrade to 2.4.4 i'm unable to login to backend area

Tags: magento, backend, magento2, upgrade, magento2.4

After upgrade to magento 2.4.4 i am not able to access the backend area; 
The access input is correct and no error is showing (it does if I put wrong password), 
it redirects me to **domain.test/backend/admin/dashboard/index/key/**..etc but the frontend stays on the login form. 
I checked that secure and unsecure urls are right,
cookie domain is set to **app.domain.test** 
I already setup and cleared cache

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the solution is:

```
bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 2560000
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue where I couldn't login to the admin console after upgrading to 2.4.4 version and didn't see any errors in the logs. config:show didn't show a value for ystem/security/max_session_size_admin, so ran the set command and I now can login to the admin panel.